# how can i run multiple methods conditionally and in parallel in C#

Tags: c#

I have some code that currently looks somewhat like this:

```
private void GetBatchJobList() //gets the list of JOBS
{
    var queuedJobList = manager.GetAllBatchJobs();
    foreach (var job in queuedJobList)
    {
        ExecuteJob(job.JobName, job.InputList); //for each JOB this method is called
    }
}

private void ExecuteJob(string jobName, string parameter)
{
    switch (jobName)
    {
        case "JobName1":
            OrderJob.JobName1(Convert.ToInt32(parameter)); 
                break;

            case "JobName2":
                OrderJob.JobName2(Convert.ToDateTime(parameter));
                break;
        }
    }
```

since you can see the methods execute one after the other. I want to run these methods parallel.
The actual names of these functions are different.
ExecuteJob does IO related work.

How do I change my code so that the function calls get executed in parallel and depending on condition ex.(JobName == JobName1).

Hope this explains it. I am just a beginner.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `ExecuteJob` doing CPU based or IO based work?

Comment: I tried to look in to Parallel.Foreach. Since i am just a beginner wasnt quite able to understand much.

Comment: @Yuval ExecuteJob does IO based work

Comment: Then perhaps consider taking advantage of the asynchronous nature of IO. Can you expose an asynchronous endpoint from `ExecuteJob`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Parallel.ForEach(manager.GetAllBatchJobs(), job => ExecuteJob(job.JobName, job.InputList))
```

Parallel runs depending on the system environment. Usually the more cpu you have, the faster it runs. But do not think that Parallel is *always* faster. E.g. if job executes quickly and there are few jobs, then sequential execution might be faster.

Further reading: [Potential Pitfalls in Data and Task Parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If his job is bound by IO, using `Parallel.ForEach` isn't likely to take him far.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy On debugging, control is not going to the ExecuteJob method. I have a timer for the thread too. some what like this: inline `void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!worker.IsBusy)
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }`

  inline `void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //whatever You want the background thread to do...
            JobsQueue j = new JobsQueue();
            j.GetBatchJobList();
        }`     so after 2 mins of wait time it will hit the timer_Elapsed method.

Comment: @Shefali sorry, it's not clear what you are doing with timer. Also if (after your edit) it's clear that you are doing IO-bound jobs, then consider to run tasks for each job and use `await Task.WhenAll` for waiting them